# My recently posted app update doesn't have latest/correct values in the info.plist file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, info.plist

I have a part in my info.plist file that stores a key metric that the app uses to know how many db's it can expect to load. It is a simple number that I change as needed. For some reason, when the app updates from the App Store with new values, it is as if the updated plist values aren't there. The app is working based on the old values.

But if I remove the application completely, and then reinstall from the App Store, it works! What am I missing here? Why wouldn't the plist file be updating correctly with an update? Is there some sort of manual copy/update process I should be doing to the Documents directory or something?

Comment: Can you write code of how you are accessing data from info.plist

Comment: You caused me to isolate the issue! I was assuming that the code for retrieving the values from the plist was doing something different than it actually was. The bounty is yours if you answer the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you write code of how you are accessing data from info.plist.

Also, remember when you are storing any data in documents directory, it will not update until you make it forcefully.

And info.plist always gets update once you update you build.

Hope it helps....